# namedtuple slow compared to tuple/dictionary/class

Tags: python-3.x

I am curious on why is namedtuple slower than a regular class in python. Consider the following:

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple

In [2]: Stock = namedtuple('Stock', 'name price shares')  

In [3]: s = Stock('AAPL', 750.34, 90)

In [4]: %%timeit 
   ...: value = s.price * s.shares
   ...:          
175 ns ± 1.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [5]: class Stock2:
   ...:     __slots__ = ('name', 'price', 'shares')
   ...:     def __init__(self, name, price, shares):
   ...:         self.name = name       
   ...:         self.price = price
   ...:         self.shares = shares

In [6]: s2 = Stock2('AAPL', 750.34, 90)

In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: value = s2.price * s2.shares
   ...:                                
106 ns ± 0.832 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [9]: class Stock3:                  
   ...:     def __init__(self, name, price, shares):
   ...:         self.name = name 
   ...:         self.price = price     
   ...:         self.shares = shares

In [10]: s3 = Stock3('AAPL', 750.34, 90)

In [11]: %%timeit                      
    ...: value = s3.price * s3.shares
    ...:         
118 ns ± 3.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [12]: t = ('AAPL', 750.34, 90)

In [13]: %%timeit         
    ...: values = t[1] * t[2]          
    ...:
93.8 ns ± 1.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [14]: d = dict(name='AAPL', price=750.34, shares=90)                                

In [15]: %%timeit                          
...: value = d['price'] * d['shares']
...:                                   
92.5 ns ± 0.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

I expected namedtuple to come before a class without slots. This is on python3.6. Also pretty amazing that dictionary's performance is comparable to a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an instance of python class, set and get attribute through dot notation is mainly through `__dict__[attribute_name]`(`__dict__` itself is an attribute, and it is a dictionary) of the instance, depending on the value of `__dict__[attribute_name]` call it `v`, there are different behaviour.

case one: `v` is not a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), so the dot notation just return `v`.
case two: `v` is a descriptor, the result would be fetched from the descriptor's `__get__` method.

For simple class instance in your description: easy it would be case one

For namedtuple situation: take a look at the [namedtuple source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L357), function `namedtuple` is making a class by using this [template](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L310), inside which named field store in the dict as a property.
Where property is descriptor, which the  [itemgetter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L265) instance would be used in the descriptor's `__get__` method!!!
Here is the property class in python code lay in the comment of the c source code in Cpython:

```
class property(object):

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        if doc is None and fget is not None and hasattr(fget, "__doc__"):
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__get = fget
        self.__set = fset
        self.__del = fdel
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, inst, type=None):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        if self.__get is None:
            raise AttributeError, "unreadable attribute"
        return self.__get(inst)

    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        if self.__set is None:
            raise AttributeError, "can't set attribute"
        return self.__set(inst, value)

    def __delete__(self, inst):
        if self.__del is None:
            raise AttributeError, "can't delete attribute"
        return self.__del(inst)
```

Summarize the above, we should understand why namedtupple access is slower, there are extra steps to get value from the instance of the class made by  `namedtuple`  than simple class.

If you want to dig deep, to see how namedtuple storing and getting value, you can read the source code of python3.6 through the above links.

An hint:
the class `namedtuple` creating is a subclass, storing the field value as tuple, and store the related index with the name of it through property.

Comment: thanks, @soulomoon. I did go through the `namedtuple` source code, and that is how I came across the name as a property finding I mentioned in my answer below. (also if one passes `verbose=True`) when construction namedtuple, the generated class gets printed.

I am marking your answer as accepted since you also provided links to the source code.

Comment: I’m not sure this is correct.  Nametuple uses dunder slots not a dunder dict, and each named field ends up being a property itemgetter hardcoded to the tuple index.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know why namedtuple's access is slower than dictionary access. Consider the following (s is a namedtuple, s2 is a regular class (without slots)):

```
In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: s.name
    ...: 
78.2 ns ± 0.713 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [17]: %%timeit
    ...: s2.name
    ...: 
58.2 ns ± 4.67 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

A simple access for namedtuple is more expensive than a class member access.

`name` in namedtuple is defined as:

```
 name = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')
```

so on doing `s.name`, python finds that name is a `property`, and then has to call an extra `__get__` method (which is `itemgetter(0)` in this case by passing `self` to it).

There might be more reasons for this as well.