# How to efficiently read large XML file and create custom objects? (Biopython SeqIO)

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

I am writing a program that takes a large XML file full of protein sequences from UniProt and analyses them. I have a working version already however that is for a smaller file. I now need to load in the full UniProt database efficiently and am unsure on how to go about it. I also want to extract specific attributes from the `SeqRecord` objects that are created so there is only the data that I am interested in. I have the following:

```py
import gzip
from Bio import SeqIO

file = "/Users/john/workspace/project-2/resources/uniprot_sprot_small.xml.gz"


def load_uniprot_records():
    records = []

    handle = gzip.open(file)
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "uniprot-xml"):
        records.append(record)
        print(record)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_uniprot_records()
```

This presents some records that look like this:

```
ID: Q6GZX4
Name: 001R_FRG3G
Description: Putative transcription factor 001R
Database cross-references: DOI:10.1016/j.virol.2004.02.019, EMBL:AY548484, GO:GO:0046782, GeneID:2947773, InterPro:IPR007031, KEGG:vg:2947773, NCBI Taxonomy:654924, Pfam:PF04947, Proteomes:UP000008770, PubMed:15165820, RefSeq:YP_031579.1, Swiss-Prot:001R_FRG3G, Swiss-Prot:Q6GZX4, SwissPalm:Q6GZX4
Number of features: 2
/dataset=Swiss-Prot
/created=2011-06-28
/modified=2019-06-05
/version=37
/accessions=['Q6GZX4']
/recommendedName_fullName=['Putative transcription factor 001R']
/gene_name_ORF=['FV3-001R']
/taxonomy=['Viruses', 'Iridoviridae', 'Alphairidovirinae', 'Ranavirus']
/organism=Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)
/organism_host=['Ambystoma', 'mole salamanders', 'Dryophytes versicolor', 'chameleon treefrog', 'Lithobates pipiens', 'Northern leopard frog', 'Rana pipiens', 'Notophthalmus viridescens', 'Eastern newt', 'Triturus viridescens', 'Rana sylvatica', 'Wood frog']
/references=[Reference(title='Comparative genomic analyses of frog virus 3, type species of the genus Ranavirus (family Iridoviridae).', ...)]
/comment_function=['Transcription activation.']
/proteinExistence=['predicted']
/keywords=['Activator', 'Complete proteome', 'Reference proteome', 'Transcription', 'Transcription regulation']
/type=['ECO:0000305']
/key=['1']
/sequence_length=256
/sequence_mass=29735
/sequence_checksum=B4840739BF7D4121
/sequence_modified=2004-07-19
/sequence_version=1
Seq('MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVE...TPL', ProteinAlphabet())
```

I want to implement an efficient function to store only the required attributes from each record in the UniProt file, which is **massive.**

So for example in the above protein, I'd want the `ID` as the main identifier, with the corresponding (since I am using this word, something tells me I should create a dictionary for this?) `Name`, `taxonomy`, `sequence_length`. However I am unsure on if I create this new data set of objects if I can still treat it as if it is a `SeqRecord` object?

I have read through the SeqRecord class documentation but it doesn't quite cover what I am trying to do so I just need a little bit of guidance with this. Sorry if it's obvious, still getting my head around some of this!

Edit:
Have now got

```py
def load_uniprot_records():
    file = "/Users/john/workspace/practical-2/resources/uniprot_sprot_small.xml.gz"
    seq_records = []

    handle = gzip.open(file)
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "uniprot-xml"):
        seq_record = SeqRecord(seq=record.seq, id=record.id,
                               name=record.name, description=record.description,
                               annotations=record.annotations)
        seq_records.append(seq_record)

    return seq_records
```

However don't know how to access just the taxonomy part of the annotations dictionary. Having `annotations=record.annotations` simply assigns every annotation, whereas I just need one or two of them (taxonomy, sequence_length). Any ideas?

Comment: I'd convert `xml` to `json`. There's a [lib](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) for that. Parsing `xml` is pain.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, SeqRecords are very complete sequence representations, but not very efficient. The most efficient data structure for your purpose is probably a simple dictionary, where the ID is key, and the value is a tuple with the fixed positions `(name, taxonomy, seq_length)` (you could also use a `namedtuple` for that, but their performance is slightly worse, I believe). Then you don't even need to store the SeqRecord, you can just extract the relevant information and then discard it:

```py
seq_records = {}  # keys remain ordered since Python 3.7 :)
for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "uniprot-xml"):
    name = record.name
    description = record.description
    seq_length = len(record)
    seq_records[record.id] = (name, description, seq_length)
```

(I don't remember the exact attribute names, you can get them using `dir(record)` or [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord-class.html), but you get the idea.) This will enable a very efficient data handling later. Do you also need an efficient parsing of the file? There might be other, faster, ways than using SeqIO, like `ElementTree` ([How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)), but unless it's a time-critical step, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I was thinking that. How would I go about just extracting those attributes and populating the dictionary? I think I need just the one loop to go over all the records in the UniProt db. However I need to minimise the amount of data because of memory. Edit: Yeah so I need to iterate record by record and just pull out the stuff I need and put it in the dictionary. I have to use SeqIO for this.

Comment: Can you check my updated post and let me know if you know how to access the annotations dictionary? I found a way to create my own SeqRecord and I will just not include the stuff I don't need. Still not too efficient but it's better than having all the stuff I'm not interested in filtered out.

Comment: This would work, even though a dictionary with tuples is probably (substantially) faster, just look at this benchmark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419132/namedtuple-slow-compared-to-tuple-dictionary-class. What do you mean by accessing the annotations dictionary? I don't think I understand your question.